# Dissect the frog

Tags: geometry, dissection

Cut the stylized frog in the picture into six pieces having the same shape and size, possibly mirrored.

[image: The frog]

The white dots are guide points. They help recognizing the shape's geometry. You are not restricted to cut along those points.

Comment: Is it possible using the white dots?

Comment: @warspyking Sure. You don't have to, but you can use the white dots as well.

Comment: Is there a solution for which each piece is made up of 9 of those unit sized squares? (I'm pretty sure I counted 54 of them in all)

Comment: @DennisMeng Yes :)

Comment: Excellent. I'll try to find that one

Comment: @Rafe Probably because I was genuinely asking since his note specified that we don't have to use it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this is the solution:

> [image: solution]

I printed out the image and cut out each unit square and then it was more easier to try out all positions.

Comment: Nice one, I've just found that solution as well, but you were faster. Good work.

Comment: Good Work! I have started from your blue section and this shape was one of my tries, but I did not try to mirror it for red one.